# NSRangeException from UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsrangeexception

I can't solve the mystery of my NSRangeException.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_countyList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Inside masterview cellforrowatindexpath.\n");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [_countyList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The exception is thrown when I have `numberOfSectionsInTableView` return 1 (there should be 1 section), but when I return 0 sections it does not throw an exception (it also does not display my data). When the code runs, it never calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The debugger takes me to the main function and I cannot see where I am accessing a NSArray for the life of me.
Any help or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You can set an exception breakpoint to debug this more easily. Simply go to the breakpoints tab in the navigator (Cmd+6) and select "Add Exception Breakpoint" in the menu of the + button at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks omz. I already had an exception breakpoint setup but it was breaking in the main() function. VinceBurn correctly guessed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using storyboard check this post.

[iOS Xcode 4.2 Master-Detail Application Template Throwing NSRangeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410522/ios-xcode-4-2-master-detail-application-template-throwing-nsrangeexception/8411272#comment10404554_8411272)

The problem you are describing look similar to that one.

Comment: Wow, thank you! That was exactly my problem. I guess the "static content" in storyboard cells are if you only want to set up the content... in the storyboard.

Comment: @NicholasMarrone: You may want to consider accepting this answer.